# Git skips merge commit when squashing using interactive rebase

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a feature using git and I have the following steps completed so far.

- Checkout new feature branch called `feature1` based on `master`
- Add couple of commits.
- Checkout new branch `test` based on `feature1`.
- Perform some changes in `test`.
- Return to (checkout to) `feature1` branch.
- Merge the `test` branch to `feature1`
- Delete `test` branch
- Edit a file, and amend the last commit to reflect the change

Here is `git log --oneline -n 5` output

```
de5d701 Merge branch 'test' into 'feature1' (amended)
a668f93 'feature1' commit3
ded7c00 'feature1' commit2
8731807 Initial 'feature1' commit
ff2f539 latest 'master' commit
```

I want to squash everything which comes after `ff2f539 latest 'master' commit` before merging to `master`. I tried to perform

```
git rebase --interactive  ff2f539
```

but the latest commit is not listed in the editor:

```
pick 8731807 Initial 'feature1' commit
pick ded7c00 'feature1' commit2
pick a668f93 'feature1' commit3

# Rebase ff2f539..de5d701 onto ff2f539
#
# Commands:
...
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

I can not understand why the latest commit which is produced by the merging of `test` branch to `feature1` branch is skipped.
Saving and exiting the editor with the following content:

```
pick 8731807 Initial 'feature1' commit
squash ded7c00 'feature1' commit2
squash a668f93 'feature1' commit3

# Rebase ff2f539..de5d701 onto ff2f539
#
# Commands:
...
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

produces new commit which does not provide the changes from the last commit

```
de5d701 Merge branch 'test' into feature1(amended)
```

They are lost. Any help how to squash all those commits into one single commit before merging to master ?

Comment: Are you sure ded7c00 is from feature1 branch and not the test branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does not show merge commits in the "interactive" list by design. It instead includes all commits that were brought into the branch by that merge. You can use `-p` (`--preserve-merges`) option to change that behavior, but it is not recommended in interactive mode, because the result may be not that obvious (see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_bugs).

But there is a simple solution without rebasing:

```
# make sure your working copy is clean, do git stash if needed
git checkout feature1
git reset --soft ff2f539
git commit -m "..."
```

This will produce one commit including all changes after ff2f539.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include merge commits in your rebase, pass the `--preserve-merges` option to `git rebase`.